# Does SqlCacheDependency use polling or query notification?

Tags: asp.net, caching, sqldependency

My Need is to build a simple configuration framework on top of a Key value table. As this is frequently used and rarely changed, would prefer to cache the table values. One requirement is if the value is changed in DB it should reflect immediately in the App. So, I planned to implement [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Web.Caching.SqlCacheDependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Doc says

> The query notification mechanism of SQL Server 2005 detects changes
>   to data that invalidate the results of an SQL query and removes any
>   cached items associated with the SQL query from the
>   System.Web.Caching.Cache

From the sample I noticed there is a property in the config called [PollTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sqlcachedependencysection.polltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Doc says

> Gets or sets the frequency with which the SqlCacheDependency polls the
>   database table for changes.

I am confused here on whether it uses the Query Notification technique or it uses Polling mechanism.

My stack is .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with SqlServer 2005 onwards(and therefore applicable to sqlserver 2008R2 ) , Sql Cache Dependency works by using the query change notification mechanism.They use a notification infrastructure and messaging system that’s built into the database, called the [**`Service Broker`**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/).

Sql server 2000 and earlier versions employed the polling mechanism.

you may be interested in further reading as suggested below::

*Jess Liberty*, author of Book: *programming in asp.net (Oreilly Media)* Says:

There is NO need to configure the database with `aspnet_regsql.exe` and there is NO need to add `<sqlCacheDependency>` element in your `web.config` in case you use sqlserver 2005 or later with Query Notification mechanism.

[**`MSDN`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164607%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) also says that :: This configuration setting i.e. `<sqlCacheDependency>` has no effect when you use the `sqlCacheDependency` element in conjunction with query notifications on SQL Server 2005. **This does means that setting the `pollTime` will have NO effect when using Query Notifications**.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a special flag or setting which I should set to make sqlCacheDependency work in conjunction with query notifications?

Comment: Yes, there are some steps to be done for enabling query notifications. check this URL: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/sqlcachedependency.aspx